# Logstash configuration to globally mutate sub index patterns

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have an ELK stack, with some configured index patterns. As part of internal requirements, I need to edit a json object (which is part of that index pattern), globally to "string".
As of now, such json object is randomly populated by numerous sub-fields, like "date", "temps", and many more others.
All of these are automatically managed by ELK, but I need all of them to be processed and converted (casted) as "strings".

So, the basic configuration is as follows:

```
type A: "long"
type B: "int"
type C: "string"
type D: "json object"
```

where type D is a nested json object which includes (as sub fields) numerous other index patterns and fields, like (for example) "typeD.date", "typeD.temps", "typeD.extrastuff", and so on.

I need all of the "`typeD*`" objects to be casted and converted as strings.
So far, I tried to use a .conf with logstash, but it did not work. I will paste my configuration after (numerous) attempts. I tried all these configuration in my own local docker environment.

The log which I tested logstash from was called log_file.json and it contains numerous sample lines, including also the index patterns I want to edit globally with this mutate operation.

```
input {
    file{
      type => "json"
      path => "/home/container/logstash/log_file.json"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      codec => json
  }
}

filter {
   if [message] =~ /\A\{.+\}\z/ {
     json {
       source => "message"
    }

  json {
    source => "[message][typeD]"
}

  mutate {
    convert => ["typeD.*","string"]
}
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "logstash-test-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
 }
  stdout{}
}
```

Also, after logging in via Kibana, I can see that the (conf) file has been correctly created and loaded by logstash, but still it fails to convert the index patterns as strings.

I would need to know which edits are necessary for the configuration to work. Does the logstash config file need some edit? Is there anything wrong in the setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a wildcard mutate like `convert => ["typeD.*","string"]`. You would have to write a ruby filter with a recursive function to iterate over all the contents of [typeD]. Something like

```
    ruby {
        code => '
            def stringify(object, name, event)
                if object == nil
                    event.set(name, "nil" )
                elsif object.kind_of?(Hash) and object != {}
                    object.each { |k, v| stringify(v, "#{name}[#{k}]", event) }
                elsif object.kind_of?(Array) and object != []
                    object.each_index { |i|
                        stringify(object[i], "#{name}[#{i}]", event)
                    }
                else
                    event.set(name, object.to_s)
                end
            end
            stringify(event.get("typeD"), "[typeD]", event)
        '
    }
```

That said, if you are sending data to elastic search you might be better of doing this in elasticsearch with a [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) that uses a wildcard to match the field name.

Comment: Hi @Badger, thanks for your answer, I am trying this now. In my previous implementation (posted on my SO question) I had a `"tags" => [0] "_jsonparsefailure"` error.
Do you know what could be the cause for this?

Comment: You are parsing three levels of nested JSON. The third one looks wrong. The json codec will parse the line of JSON read from the file. Then you (conditionally) parse the [message] field that was parsed from the JSON. Then you parse [message][typeD], I think you mean [typeD] there.

Comment: Hi @badger, the edit works perfectly (I have tested it on a log on my machine), but when I test it with a continuous log stream from Beats, I have a looped error.
Could it be that this edit can work only with a saved "static" json log file, and not with a continuous log stream from Beats?