# Possibility of configuring logstash to globally mutate index patterns from a Beats input stream

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elastic-beats

I have searched on the ELK discussion forum and received no answer. I had this task linked here ["Logstash configuration to globally mutate sub index patterns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907508/logstash-configuration-to-globally-mutate-sub-index-patterns) and it was correctly solved - the logtsash configuration worked and I was able to globally cast everything to string as the index pattern.

However, when I set this configuration to work not from a static log file saved locally, but from a beats input stream, the configuration (Ruby filter) linked by badger on Stackoverflow did not work. Do you think this is doable with that ruby filter?

Upon apply of that edit on the beats input stream, the global casting of "typeD" to "string" did not work at all and resulted in redundant errors.

My beats configuration is listed below:

```
input { 
  beats { 
    port => 5044 
    type => "json"
  }
}
         
filter {
  
 ruby {
        code => '
            def stringify(object, name, event)
                if object == nil
                    event.set(name, "nil" )
                elsif object.kind_of?(Hash) and object != {}
                    object.each { |k, v| stringify(v, "#{name}[#{k}]", event) }
                elsif object.kind_of?(Array) and object != []
                    object.each_index { |i|
                        stringify(object[i], "#{name}[#{i}]", event)
                    }
                else
                    event.set(name, object.to_s)
                end
            end
            stringify(event.get("typeD"), "[typeD]", event)
        '
    }  

}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    cloud_id => "${cid}"
    cloud_auth => "${cau}"
    ilm_enabled => "false"
    template_name => "${app}" 
    index => "${app}-logstash-${env}-%%{[@metadata][version]}-%%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: The type of the input makes no difference for the `filter` and `output` blocks, they have no information about it, only the message format is important, your issue is being caused by other things. What is the message you are trying to parse and what is the error?

Comment: I am trying to parse various application logs just as they pass by through Beats. 
A sample error is:
`<LogStash::Event:0x1687783c>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"my_application-logstash-dev-7.12.0-2021.06.15", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"rw51EHoByCcwpw2qVLvh", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [typeD] tried to parse field **[typeD]** as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}`